# Google OAuth Authorized redirect URI not taking effect

Tags: google-oauth

I just hosted my app on a new URL I've set up on my apache server.

say `https://app.mysite.com`, and I forgot to include this new URL on my google oauth credentials,
so I added these:
**Authorized JavaScript Origins:** https://app.mysiste.com 
**Authorized redirect URIs:** https://app.mysite.com/oauth/callback

I initially assumed that it would take some time before it actually works, so I waited 15 minutes. but its already past 15mins and I am still stuck at `https://app.mysite.com/oauth/callback`, not redirecting me to my site's dashboard.

Does it need more time to take effect or did I just mess up somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try using window.location for wherever you need to redirect